# Calculate `dot` product of image and vector

Tags: python, matrix, vector, pytorch

I would like to calculate something like dot product of vector and image with shapes:

- (3)
- (3,1080,1080)

and the output should be (1,1080,1080)

```
img = torch.rand((3,1080,1080))
R_coefficient=float(0.2126)
G_coefficient=float(0.7152)
B_coefficient=float(0.0722)
Y = img[0,...]*R_coefficient + img[1,...]*G_coefficient img[2,...]*B_coefficient
```

This code above gives me results, I look for, but I would like to use **PyTorch** utils like **torch.dot**, **torch.matmul** etc.

I have tried these

```
TensorImage(torch.dot(img[:,...],RGB_vector[:]))
TensorImage(torch.matmul(img,RGB_vector[:]))
```

These two options give me an errors connecting with shape, I have rejected them.

```
RGB_vector = torch.tensor([[[0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722]]], dtype=img.dtype).permute(2,1,0)
    #     torch.t(RGB_vector)
        print(RGB_vector.shape)
        print(img.shape)
        return TensorImage(img[:,...]*RGB_vector)#.unsqueeze_(0)
```

this sample above works, but I am getting image with shape **(3,1080,1080)**, but I need to get 1 instead of 3 at the first shape's dimension

**Current working example**

```
import torch
img = torch.rand((3,1080,1080))
RGB_vector = torch.tensor([[[0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722]]], dtype=img.dtype).permute(2,1,0)
print(RGB_vector.shape)
print(img.shape)
TensorImage(img[:,...]*RGB_vector).unsqueeze_(0)
```

Greetings,
DA

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
You say that you would like to use PyTorch methods, but you've shown no attempt to do so.  This post is not yet ready for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Firstfully, I dont wanna to share tens lines of code, as you know for sure, when someone tries to make something "works", then there are a lot of samples and secondally, I always thought, that StackOverflow solves problem. I am just stuck with this for many many hours, and I just dont know, how to compare shapes between images shape and vector described above

Comment: I will add suitable code snippets from my attempts

Comment: @Prune, plecase check this now, forgive me for you inconvenience

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Done, I have attached current working example at the end of my question, greetings to you @Prune

Comment: You can do this in numpy by doing `np.average(img,weights=[.2126,.7152,.0722],axis=0)`.

Comment: That's the missing piece, then: your product is doing a weighted average.  Your code is still missing the supporting `import` statements, but perhaps someone will supply them for you.

Comment: aaaa sorry :( forgive me Prune

Comment: thanks @Tim Roberts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This can delivers the correct shape but Im not sure if that's what you need)

So a tensor multiplication where the second tensor has dim >2 seems to work when the last dimension of the first tensor equals the second dimension of the second tensor.

```py
v = torch.rand(3).unsqueeze(0)
m = torch.rand(3, 1080, 1080).transpose(0, 1)
r = torch.matmul(v, m).transpose(0, 1)

print(r.shape)
```

```
>>> torch.Size([1, 1080, 1080])
```

Answer (score 3):

To modify as little of your sample as possible:

```
import torch
img = torch.rand((3,1080,1080))
RGB_vector = torch.tensor([[[0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722]]], dtype=img.dtype).permute(2,1,0)

return torch.mean(img * RGB_vector, axis=0).unsqueeze(0)
```

This will return a (1, 1080, 1080) tensor.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your answers, I have dealed with `torch.einsum` and finally it looks like

```py
import torch
img = torch.rand((3,1080,1080))
vec = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3]).t()
result = torch.einsum("i,ijk->jk", vec, img))
```